# how do I force recompilation a certain code block from source smarty tpl file

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I've a tpl file which has dynamic code that gets cached and defeats the whole purpose. I've tried this:

```
{include file="./fileWithDynamicCode.tpl" nocache}
```

But it loads the first time and display nothing on the second run (well it wasn't in the cache directory so didn't get picked up, I guess). Also,

```
{nocache}
{if $context && $context->id eq $mmdf['someitems']}
    {{assign var="point" value="active"}}
{else}
    {{assign var="point" value="dactive"}}
{/if}
{/nocache}
```

Again, it works for the first time only.

I'm looking for a way to recompile this portion of code right from the source on every reload rather than from cache dir.

Is there something I should do on the backend. Thanks.

Comment: @Scuzzy did you change your comment. i was considering the php one you posted. can you please post that again

Comment: I posted `$smarty->compile_check = true` and `$smarty->force_compile = true` might be worth looking into. Don't forget smarty has two aspects of cache, there's a compiled PHP template and a possible static html version.

Comment: @Scuzzy well it can't be actually used in production.

Comment: do you have logic that checks if the page is cached or not and sets assignments? ie are the vars in your no cache block assigned all the time?

Comment: is there any syntax in php to check if a tpl cached or not?? how do i force recompile using php

Comment: there is [isCached()](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.is.cached.tpl) which you can use to determin if the template output is cached, at which point you then assign what you need if not cached (eg don't do Database work if the page is cached). the biggest thing with smarty is genearting a unique cache ID for your page I feel. ie a given request nets a specific cache ID when referencing the same templated file.

Comment: @Scuzzy thanks for your time. I'll dig into the suggestions and get back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling cache and recompilation? Check following menu in the backend:

> Advanced Parameters -> Performance

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I certainly don't want to do it in Production.

Comment: you can at least try and see if this helps. Moreover in the production environment there will not be frequent changes in the template files, everytime something has been modified just clear the cache once (from the same page) and the changes will be reflected

Comment: I'd already tried it and it works, though i still don't want to loose on caching and my main concern is `{nocache}` thing which doesn't seem to be working the way it's expected to. re read the question